# S-composite as a product of s-primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I have $S=\{1, 5, 9, ...\}$ which is the set of positive integers of the form $4k+1$.

$S$-primes are numbers in the set with only $1$ and themselves as factors. $S$-composites are the rest.

I am trying to find an example of an $S$-composite that can be expressed a product of $S$-primes in more than one way.

So far, I am thinking that I need to find two pairs of one $S$-prime and a "proper" prime $S$-prime that multiply to a $S$-composite. I've had a go at these but don't seem to be getting anywhere. I would imagine there is a way of doing it algebraically but I can't figure it out.

A small push in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: The first integer $\equiv 1 \bmod 4$ for which unique factorization fails is $9 . 49 = 21^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close - try multiplying two $S$-primes with neither of them being real primes.

Answer (score 0):

Every integer has a unique prime decomposition (i.e., can only be written as a product of primes in one way, up to the ordering of the factors).

Since every $S$-composite is an integer, this is also true for $S$-composits. If $n$ is an $S$-composit such that $$n=p_1^{n_1}\cdots p_k^{n_k}$$ where $p_i$ are all $S$-primes, then the above factorisation presents a prime factorisation of $n$ into prime factors, meaning it is unique.